# Is there any way to solve ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. in Flutter?

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, gradle

I have been working on a project which depends on Firebase Cloud Firestore, and Bluetooth Serial Communication between a IoT device.

So i have been trying to use [Flutter blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue).

It is giving me errors like
**Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)**

Provide me with the fix please

Full Log is given below:

```
>Launching lib\main.dart on Emulator in debug mode...
 lib\main.dart
Plugin project :firebase_auth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :firebase_core_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Plugin project :cloud_firestore_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.
Parameter format not correct -
Note: C:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_blue-0.7.2\android\src\main\java\com\pauldemarco\flutter_blue\FlutterBluePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteOutput found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ArraysByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$BoundedByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar otobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$IntList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter$Converter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$LongList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.11.0) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1.jar (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)

  Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.11.0.jar 
  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 56s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: I have the same issue with flutter_blue. Did you solved this problem?